# "Is there any option to suppress just the Alert recovery mail in stackdriver on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

"I get alert mail from stackdriver whenever some pipeline takes more time then it's required time but after some time/days whenever that pipeline works the expected right behavior again,Stackdriver sends out a Alert Recovery mail.I want to disable just the recovery mail because i don't want to get that recovery mail is there any option in gcp to do this ?"

"I have read the google docs for GCP's Stackdriver but i couldn't find the solution"

Comment: Could you specify the type of pipeline you're referring to? Is it a Dataflow pipleine or some other custom resource you've deployed?

Comment: yes it is a Dataflow pipeline @JudyTRaj

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to suppress the alert recovery notification. Some people create a mail filter to filter out the recovery notification.